# how to prevent some route tracking in antonioribeiro/tracker laravel package

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [antonioribeiro/tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) laravel package to Store stats.

Now,I have a routes for Admin directory like this :

```
Route::group(
    array (
        'middleware' => 'IsAdmin',
        'as'         => 'admin::'
    ),
    function () {
        Route::get('desktop', [ 'uses' => 'DesktopController@index']);
                //some Other Routes 
        }
);
```

And I do not want to track this routes and sub routes.

For that I change do_not_track_routes option like this :

```
'do_not_track_routes' => [
        'admin.*',
        'tracker.stats.*',
    ],
```

But seems this does not work and with every visits Admin or sub Admin directories , add new sessions (or visits) to **tracker_sessions** table.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified not to track `admin.*`, but your routes are going to be named `admin::*`.

You need to either change your route group to be `'as' => 'admin.'`, or you need to change your `do_not_track_routes` to exclude `'admin::*'`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689204/laravel-do-not-track-routes-with-antonioribeiro-tracker

Was answering the same question, and find the answer by myself (with a lot of debug ...) It work for me ;)