# Laravel, do not track routes with `antonioribeiro/tracker`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm currently using `antonioribeiro/tracker` for some stats on my Laravel.

I'm struggling using the `do_not_track_routes` array in the config.

I just try to disable the tracker to track admin route, but it doesn't work.

```
    'do_not_track_routes' =>
    [
    'admin.*',
    ]

    /* Admin routes */
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'as'=>'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin1452872135', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin', 'language']], function () {
        //some route
    });
```

Even this keep the tracker to insert new sessions...

```
    'do_not_track_routes' =>
    [
    '*',
    ]
```

I really try everything that came to my mind, I'll be thankfull for some help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get my own answer after debugging inside the package ...
In fact, `do_not_track_routes` is never used in the `Tracker.php` (`vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Tracker.php`)

So I update the isTrackable method like that :

```
protected function isTrackable() {
    return $this->config->get('enabled') &&
    $this->logIsEnabled() &&
    $this->parserIsAvailable() &&
    $this->isTrackableIp() &&
    $this->isTrackableEnvironment() &&
    $this->notRobot() &&
    $this->isTrackableRoute();
}
```

And add this new method, to check if the current URL is in the `do_not_track_route`array :

```
protected function isTrackableRoute() {
    if (is_null(\Request::path())) {
            return true;
    }
    $routes = $this->config->get('do_not_track_routes');
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $match = preg_grep ('/'. $route .'/i', [\Request::path()]);
            if(!empty($match)){
                return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Work well for me, if you find a better answer, I'm in ! :)

Comment: Your solution could solve my problem. thanks @Jiedara.

Answer (score 0):

You must indicate your route's *name* (not the URI) under `do_not_track_routes`.

So if your route is defined as `'as'=>'admin'` your tracker config must be

```
'do_not_track_routes' =>
[
    'admin',
]
```

In response to @Jiedara, `do_not_track_routes` is used in `PragmaRX\Tracker\Data\Repositories\Route` which checks if it includes `$route->currentRouteName()`. `$route` is an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Router` and the `currentRouteName()` method indeed provides the route's name.